# How do I get the linked table using LINQ?

Tags: .net, linq

I have two tables called Table1 and Table2 which have a 1-1 relationship.

In LINQ, I have a collection of entities of Table1. Is it possible using LINQ to extract all of the Table2 counterparts of each Table1 entity in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EntityFramework, you probably want [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx).  Here's an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) that explains many of the ways to load related entities for Entity Framework.

If you're using LinqToSql, you might want [LoadWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534268.aspx).  Here's an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic11) that explains many of the ways to load related entities for LinqToSql.

---

If you just have plain old instances, you can do this:

```
List<Table1> items = GetList();
List<Table2> relatedItems = items.Select(t1 => t1.Table2).ToList();
```

It's probably not a good idea to do this kind of code with the ORM technologies mentioned above, as they may generate one query to the database per original instance.